# how to convert any type of video to mp4?

Tags: php, video, video-conversion

how can i let users upload video to mp4 using php code?  I've been trying to find a code that converts video to mp4 automatically no mater what type of video format it is  this possible?

Comment: I would like to have the code in the website when someone uploads a video it will automatically convert it to mp4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are trying this at your server/ not using any online tool.
You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for this. 
Sample code for conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i {input}.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 {output}.mp4
```

FFmpeg is most widely used tool for this purpose and you can download the same [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Comment: in addition to run it in a php script just type something like  shell_exec('code above');

Answer (score 0):

```
//This code convert video to mp4 format.
//for that you have to install HandBrakeCLI on your linux server
system("HandBrakeCLI -i ".$currfileName." -o ".$new_convertedvideo.".mp4 -v -m -E aac,ac3 -e x264");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you run it directly in php file.

```
$folder = '/path/to/uploads/folder/';
$filename = 'your_video_file.avi';
$newFilename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME).'.mp4';

exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i '.$folder.$filename.' -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags faststart -hide_banner '.$folder.$newFilename.' 2>&1', $out, $res);

if($res != 0) {
    error_log(var_export($out, true));
    error_log(var_export($res, true));

    throw new \Exception("Error!");
}
```