# Can't Play video in android uploaded from iphone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, video

I have upload and play videos on both Android and iPhone devices but video uploaded from iPhone is not working on Android.it's not play in android video player. It's give me error message

> "sorry this video can not be played"

video is in mp4 format.

Comment: Please check the format types supported on server and also in your app's code. If .mov is not supported please add it :)

Comment: @Ashutosh video befour post on server it is convert in to mp4 format.

Comment: can this video be played in iOS device?

Comment: yes, ios can play that video and also play all the videos posted from android device.only ios posted video can't play in android device.

Comment: then you should go with Biraj Zalavadia's ans..

Comment: yes,sure i will try for this.thanks

Comment: iOS video format should be .mov so it's not mp4 for real, just the extension. Android can't play .mov by default. In my case I've installed the VLC app for Android and it works just fine. Maybe it fits in your scenario too

Answer (score 10):

Yes, That's right.

It happens because the android support limited codecs in-built like mp3,mp4,mpeg.

While iphone support most of codecs.

**What is the way to resolve this?**

MP4 for video and MP3 for audio are widely accepted and work on both platforms.

So you need do some stuff at the server. Implement the ffmpeg library that will convert all the videos to MP4 and audio to MP3.

We are doing same mechanism to resolve this issue.

Find FFMPEG implementation for PHP [Here](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) and

Command to convert all videos to MP4 [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580370/how-to-convert-any-type-of-video-to-mp4)
Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i will check also this part to implementation.

Comment: Is your web service in php?

Comment: You will find the code easily for this implementation. You need to create cron job and corn will run periodically and convert the video to MP4

Comment: OK sure,let me impalement this thing on server side.

Answer (score 9):

If it is mp4, then you need to check what codecs are used. iPhone usually encodes everything in h264, however, there are different profiles of h264 and high profiles might not be supported on Android, because they are more complex for decoding.

Even apple says in their documentation:

> H.264 Baseline Level 3.0, Baseline Level 3.1, Main Level 3.1, and High Profile Level 4.1.
>
> iPad, iPhone 3G, and iPod touch (2nd generation and later) support
>   H.264 Baseline 3.1. If your app runs on older versions of iPhone or
>   iPod touch, however, you should use H.264 Baseline 3.0 for
>   compatibility. If your content is intended solely for iPad, Apple TV,
>   iPhone 4 and later, and Mac OS X computers, you should use Main Level
>   3.1.

Baseline profile should be played everywhere.

See the list here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles

So if you have control over encoding (if the video is recorded from your iOS application), then you can do it programmatically. I just googled and found a piece of code where the profile is set: http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1512924.html