# Does PHP have voice conversion library for 3gpp to mp4

Tags: php

I need to convert an upload voice file from 3gpp format to mp4 format in PHP server code.
I googled but there seems no conversion library for this purpose. Can I do that in PHP and is there exist any library for it?

Thanks

Comment: try this -> http://www.ffmpeg.org/ taken from this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580370/how-to-convert-any-type-of-video-to-mp4

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK php don't have any library for this purposes, but you can always use `ffmpeg` for conversions:

```
ffmpeg -i test.3gp -sameq -ab 64k -ar 44100 test.mp4
```

Someone asked about how to convert 3gp to mp4 in the official forums, so you can take a look: http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/3gp-to-mp4-td942632.html (the example has been taken from there)